# Custom claim not refreshed

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, jwt, authorization, claims-based-identity

Custom claims set is not updating. I have two API and an MVC project API1 validates the user and set claims, API2 is supposed to consume the custom claims, MVC is the UI.

The below code is from API1 that runs successfully. The claims are added. I can see the same in API2, (but it's now visible anywhere else including the MVC. maybe I don't know how to access it).

But the main problem is not that, the main problem is, the claims are not updated when it's changed the next time through API1. So, even if another user login in the claim still shows the first users' claims.

```
 public async Task<AuthenticationModel> GetTokenAsync(LoginRequestModel model)
        {

            //...

            if (await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, model.Password))
            {
                JwtSecurityToken jwtSecurityToken = await CreateJwtToken(user, model.Database);
                authenticationModel.Token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(jwtSecurityToken);

            }
        }


        private async Task<JwtSecurityToken> CreateJwtToken(ApplicationUser user, string myClaimValue)
        {
            var userClaims = await _userManager.GetClaimsAsync(user);
            var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);

            var roleClaims = new List<Claim>();

            for (int i = 0; i < roles.Count; i++)
            {
                roleClaims.Add(new Claim("roles", roles[i]));
            }

            var claims = new[]
            {
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, user.UserName),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Email, user.Email),
                new Claim("uid", user.Id),
                new Claim("MyCustomClaim", myClaimValue)
            }
            .Union(userClaims)
            .Union(roleClaims);

            var symmetricSecurityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_jwt.Key));
            var signingCredentials = new SigningCredentials(symmetricSecurityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

            var jwtSecurityToken = new JwtSecurityToken(
                issuer: _jwt.Issuer,
                audience: _jwt.Audience,
                claims: claims,
                expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(_jwt.DurationInMinutes),
                signingCredentials: signingCredentials);
            return jwtSecurityToken;
        }
```

This data is used in the following code. It works for the first time, but when the values are changed in API1, the same is not reflected in the claims. The claim always shows the first value assigned to it. I tried getting details of the claim in the MVC for debug and initialization, but everywhere else the claims are empty.

```
 protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);

            var identity = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
            if (identity != null)
            {
                IEnumerable<Claim> claims = identity.Claims;
                var myclaim= identity.FindFirst("MyCustomClaim").Value;
               
            }
            optionsBuilder.LogTo(Console.WriteLine, LogLevel.Information);
        }
```

Comment: The problem cannot be reproduced according to the code you provided. It is recommended that you debug to see where the problem went.

Comment: Thankyou Chaodeng. It was my mistake. Thank you very much for your efforts.